# If $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, what is $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\exp(x)}{a+\exp(x)}\right)$ for $a>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ be a normal random variable. I'm interested in a new random variable, defined as 
$$
z = \frac{\exp(x)}{a+\exp(x)},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}, a>0.
$$
More specifically, I would like to find the closed form (if any) of its expected value, $\mathbb{E}[z]$, but I don't know how to proceed.

As a first step I could use an intermediate random variable $y=\exp(x)$, which follows the log-normal distribution (since $x$ is normal) and its mean and variance are given w.r.t. to $x$'s mean and variance. But again, I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: so mainly you want $E(z)$, isn't?

Comment: @MANMAID, yes :)

Comment: The question title asks to find the distribution of the ratio which is not difficult - but the body asks for a closed-form for the expectation (which may not have a convenient closed form, or certainly is not easy).

Comment: @wolfies you' re not wrong in general, even though I don't understand this comment completely. As far as I know, we say that we know the distribution of a rv when we know its pdf, but I'm probably wrong. I just edited the title; hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Why the minor edit? To artificially push your question to the front page?

Comment: @Did: Even worse: just take a look at the edit history to see that the OP has engaged in this type of behaviour several times already. **Nullgepeto**, stop this or I shall flag your post to a moderator! If you want to make your post more visible offer a bounty.

Comment: @Did, Alex M, I'd like to apologize. I indeed did this to put the question "up to recent"; didn't realize that this is a bad behavior, honestly. I'll stop this. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Can you find the value of your integral for $a=1$?

Answer (score 4):

You want to compute the expectation of $\frac{\exp(X)}{a+\exp(X)}$ for $X \gets \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $a>0$.

Firstly, we can simplify the problem by removing one of the parameters. We have $\frac{\exp(X)}{a+\exp(X)} = \frac{1}{1+a\cdot\exp(-X)} = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-(X-\log a))}$. Thus $\underset{X \gets \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)}{\mathbb{E}}\left[\frac{\exp(X)}{a+\exp(X)}\right] = \underset{X \gets \mathcal{N}(\mu-\log a,\sigma^2)}{\mathbb{E}}\left[\frac{1}{1+\exp(-X)}\right].$ So without loss of generality $a=1$.

The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$ is known as the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

Thus the distribution of $f(X)$ for $X \gets \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the [logit-Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution). Unfortunately, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution) the mean has no analytic expression.

If you want to compute the mean nonetheless, this article may be useful:

> [John B. Holmes & Matthew R. Schofield (2022) Moments of the logit-normal distribution, Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods, 51:3, 610-623, DOI: 10.1080/03610926.2020.1752723](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03610926.2020.1752723)

In particular, the above referenced paper gives the following formula for the mean:
[image: Proposition 1 of Holmes & Schofield (2022)]

---

Now an informal explanation for why this is so hard to compute: We could compute $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ by computing a Taylor series $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(\mu)}{k!} (x-\mu)^k$ and then using [the moments of the Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments), i.e., $$\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(\mu)}{k!} \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^k] = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(2\ell)}(\mu)}{(2\ell-1)!!}.$$
(Since $f(x) = \frac12 + \frac12 \tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, we could use [the Taylor series for $\tanh$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Taylor_series).)
Unfortunately, $f$ has a pole at the value $\pi i$ in the complex plane, as [$1+\exp(\pi i) = 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity). Even though we aren't interested in complex values, this tells us that the Taylor series has a finite radius of convergence. Since we are evaluating this on a Gaussian which is supported on the entire real line, this is a problem.

Answer (score -2):

If we apply a [random variable transformation](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf) $Z = g(X)$

$f_Z(z)=f_X(g^{-1}(z))|\frac{d}{dz}g^{-1}(z)|$

where $g(X)=\frac{\exp[X]}{a+ \exp[X]}$, $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \, \pi} \, \sigma}\exp[-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}]$, and $g^{-1}(z)=\log\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a\,z}-\frac{1}{a}}\right)$

$f_Z(z)= \frac{e^{-\frac{\left(\mu -\log \left(-\frac{a z}{z-1}\right)\right)^2}{2 \sigma
   ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma  \left| (z-1) z\right| }$

Finally

$E[Z]=\int z\,f_Z(z)dz = \frac{\int \frac{z e^{-\frac{\left(\mu -\log \left(-\frac{a z}{z-1}\right)\right)^2}{2
   \sigma ^2}}}{\left| (z-1) z\right| } \, dz}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }$

Answer (score -3):

$F_Z(z)=P(Z\le z)=P(\frac{1}{1+ae^{-X}}\le z) = P(Ln(\frac{az}{1-z}) \le X) = F_X(Ln(\frac{az}{1-z}) )$

So $f_Z(z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}F_X(Ln(\frac{az}{1-z}) )  = \frac{1}{z(1-z)} f_X(Ln(\frac{az}{1-z}))$. Where $f_X$ is the usual normal density function. 
I don't think this will leave you much wiser so better to go after $E[Z]$ directly.